# Facebook OpenGraph: Submitting an new action

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm just starting out with Facebook SSO and OpenGraph. I have SSO working with my iOS app and now I'm starting to see how to publish OpenGraph actions.

I've set up a new Action Type and I need to submit it. When I do, I get the error:

> You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type. Review the documentation.

Ok, so I click the helpful documentation link and it tells me I want to do this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook?recipe=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

So I translate that into this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/fotoferret:hug?ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

fotoferret is my namespace, hug is my action

where MY_ACCESS_TOKEN is the value returned by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET
```

When I pasted my translated URL I get this error back:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

an this point I'm confused. I've tried publishing an action to my timeline, but it tells me a I need an active access token, which I've provided. So how can I publish an action?

Comment: Could you query the access_token you have with the debugger? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Didn't know about that! When I do, It till me that it as App ID for my app.

Comment: Ok it's an app token then. As stated below, you cannot use /me with an app access_token

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using an app access token please use the ID of the user not `/me`. You are doing actions on behalf of the app not directly of the user.

*User Access Token*

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/fotoferret:hug?ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`

*App Access Token*

`https://graph.facebook.com/ID/fotoferret:hug?ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`

When using the Graph Explorer be sure to switch the option to `POST` and not get `GET`. `GET` is set by default so it will return the actions not create one.

Or using cURL

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-F 'ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' \
https://graph.facebook.com/ID/fotoferret:hug
```

If you have "Requires App Token to Publish" enabled and get

`{"error":{"message":"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.","type":"OAuthException","code":15}}`

It means you are using

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_ACCESS_USER_TOKEN' \
-F 'ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' \
https://graph.facebook.com/me/fotoferret:hug
```

Use `MY_APP_TOKEN`. If you get,

`{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}`

it means you are using

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN' \
-F 'ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' \
https://graph.facebook.com/me/fotoferret:hug
```

You should use the numeric id

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN' \
-F 'ferret=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' \
https://graph.facebook.com/ID/fotoferret:hug
```

If you get

`{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}`

The user doesn't have publish_actions actions in their set for me/permissions, it should be there as `"publish_actions": 1` if it is not, grant the permission by selecting "Get Access Token" and choosing (you must change to suit in your app code scope as well)

Comment: Just to clarify, in your User Access example, "me" should be replaced by the numeric id of the facebook user, and in the App Access token example, ID should be replaced by the numeric id of the App? Also, should MY_ACCESS_TOKEN be the long one or the short one with the | in the middle?

Comment: @PaulCezanne For the user access token, /me is okay. For the app token, which is what you have (the one with the |), the numeric id must be used. If you use `oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET` you are asking for an app access token.

Comment: ok, almost there. So I have "me" in my URL and I have the long user access token, and when I paste that into Firefox I get nice JSON back (with null data). So it looks like it worked. But I'm back where I started, because when I click Submit from the Open Graph dashboard I still get the error "You must first publish..."

Comment: @PaulCezanne As far as I know, all browser requests in a URL bar are `GET` requests so you would need to test it either in the Graph Explorer or cURL as I have shown above. It will not work in Firefox because you will be pulling for a `GET`. A successful result is the id of the Open Graph action, not null data.

Comment: ok, I've switched to curl, not a problem. When I run the "me" version I got back "requires extended permissions, publish_actions," which I forgot to grant. I then got a new user access token, curl'd it again, and now it is tellig me "This method must be called with an app access token.!"

Comment: @PaulCezanne it most likely means you have "Requires App Token to Publish" set in your action type setup. Use the App Token, that's what you started with :)

Comment: and what is the app token then? I've tried generating one with explorer, asking for publish_action permission, still getting the error message. (I don't mind moving to chat if you're ok with it...) And thanks so much for your help so far!!!!

Comment: Sure you can find me in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7473/facebook-developers

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier if you use the [graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to generate an access token for you app and use that. That would at least eliminate any chance of error from your fetching the access token.

Comment: Just went there, got one of the "long" access tokens, not the kind with the | in it, and put that into my http string. Submitted that, didn't get an error back, just some JSON with a null "data" and filled out "paging" section. Went back to the OpenGraph actions page, tried to submit it and got the same error: "You must publish..."